# Loop in C help!

Tags: c, for-loop

My friends tell me that a special loop exists that isn't a 'while' loop or a 'do while' loop.

Does anyone know what it's called and the correct syntax for it's use?

Comment: You should consider getting a good, introductory book on C, like one of those listed in [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks James, I have a book on C but I read the first chapter and got bored.

Comment: @Hades if you got bored in the 1st chapter of a C book, what are you doing here?

Comment: Yeah, we can tell, you got bored. How come do you know about safety of exceptions thrown form DLLs and don't know loops in C?

Comment: Getting bored reading the first chapter could mean that you get bored easily or that you simply had a bad book. Since there is only 1 way to be sure, can I suggest you try some other book?

Comment: Try another C book then. This one is pretty entertaining: http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt

Comment: For someone with a decent bit of exposure to programming, the first chapter of ANY learn-to-program-in-XXX book is bound to be boring.

Comment: @tdammers: I haven't thoroughly read a language tutorial in years, but I can't imagine getting caught in the situation Hades seems to be in. I look for grammar/syntax, a library reference, and any coding standards people have posted. By that point, I ought to know all the loop constructs!

Comment: @Nicholas Knight: Yeah, I also haven't read a programming book in the order of chapters for years... quite surprised some programmers actually start at the beginning. Maybe the kind of people that also read copyright notice and ISBN code ? They are usually quite boring.

Comment: -1 I can't in good conscience vote to close this, since it really is a programming question, but per @Maciej's comment, it is a waste of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A setjmp loop perhaps? That is pretty special.

```
static jmp_buf buf;

int i = 0;
if ( setjmp(buf) < end ) {
    /* do stuff */
    longjmp(buf, i++);
}
```

Comment: Evil. BTW, why is the `jmp_buf` declared `static`?

Comment: Global variables declared static are not visible in other compilation units. I think it defaults to "int" that way.

Comment: To limit its scope to the current translation unit scope? Otherwise an ingenious programmer might define **extern jmp_buf buf** in another file, and jump to the above loop from there. Now this would be evil...

Answer (score 16):

A for loop maybe?

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: If you used 42 instead of 15, your loop would be the answer to life, this question, the universe and everything.

Comment: No, it would stop one step before reaching the answer.

Comment: Why is 42 such a crucial number? :) +1 for for-loop though. That made me chuckle.

Comment: @AJ google calculator can help show why: http://www.google.com/search?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything

Answer (score 10):

A goto loop perhaps? That is pretty special.

```
start:
       /* do stuff */
       if ( !done ) goto start;
```

Comment: Special in an awful scary way.

Comment: +1 Yeah, The goto loop is pretty special. I can't really consider the for loop special, so this must be the correct answer. :P

Comment: Special, I think, as in "special education" in the US.

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 kind of loops in `c`.

The for loop: http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-for-loop-statement.aspx

```
for (initialization_expression;loop_condition;increment_expression){
  // statements
}
```

The while loop: http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-while-loop-statement.aspx

```
while (expression) {
  // statements
}
```

The do while loop: http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-do-while-loop-statement.aspx

```
do {
  // statements
} while (expression);
```

And you can emulate loops with a function ofcourse:

Emulating a do while loop:

```
void loop(int repetitions){
    // statements
    if(repetitions != 0){
        loop(repetitions - 1);
    }
}
```

Emulating a while loop:

```
void loop(int repetitions){
    if(repetitions != 0){
        // statements
        loop(repetitions - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A signal handler loop perhaps? That is pretty special.

```
#include <signal.h>

void loop(int signal)
{
    if ( !done ) {
        /* do stuff */
        raise(SIGINT);
    }
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, loop);
    raise(SIGINT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're the king of special loops!

Comment: Well, I am very good at knowing what NOT to do in production code.

Comment: Depending on your system's signal semantics, this could simply exit (default `SIGINT` behavior) after the first round.

Answer (score 6):

There's the `for` loop, although I don't know how *special* I'd consider it.

Comment: A `for` loop *could* be considered a special case of a `while` loop.

Comment: I would say that it most certainly is a fancy while loop.

Comment: ...And a `while` loop is nothing more than a dressed up set pair of jump/goto and conditional statements.

Comment: However, the fact that in C (and C++) is nothing than syntactic sugar for a while loop may be misleading. This is not the situation in some other languages, where the semantics of *while* and *for* loops are clearly different: the iteration count a *while* loop may be unknown before the loop is entered. Not so for a *for* loop, where the iteration count is known before entering the loop, and changing the loop counter is not allowed from within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

and don't forget recursion

```
void doSomething(int i)
{
    if(i > 15)
        return;
    /* do stuff */
    doSomething(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you left out a for(;true;) loop

Answer (score 0):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269714/c-abbreviated-for-loop-executed-only-once/2269829#2269829) could help you understand how C *for loop* works

Answer (score 0):

infinite loop ?

for(;;){
}

I like this one :-)

Answer (score 0):

A [Y combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_combinator) loop? That's special enough to be apple only (for now). Also special enough to leak memory all over the place

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Block.h>

typedef void * block;
typedef block (^block_fn)(block);
typedef void (^int_fn)(int);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    block_fn Y = ^ block(block f) {
        return ((block_fn) ^ block(block_fn x) {
                return x(x);
            })(^ block(block_fn x) {
                    return ((block_fn)f)(Block_copy(^ block(block y) {
                                return ((block_fn)(x(x)))(y);
                            }));
                });
    };

    int_fn loop = Y(^ block(int_fn f) {
            return Block_copy(^ (int a) {
                    if (a <= 0) {
                        printf("loop done\n");
                    } else {
                        printf("loop %d\n", a);
                        f(a - 1);
                    }
                });
        });
    loop(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 for some non-C language in the answer to a question tagged C

Comment: @R this is C as interpreted by Apple's versions of gcc or clang: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension%29

Comment: I will, however, accept -1 for posting such a useless and hideous answer. It is C though